# The type initializer for 'Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Internal.carbon_csharpPINVOKE' threw an exception

Tags: speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

Ran into this issue with .NET Framework 4.7.1, however it does not throw an exception and works in .NET Core 2.0
Got this error in .NET when the following line is executed

var recognizer = factory.CreateSpeechRecognizer();

> {"The type initializer for
>   'Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Internal.carbon_csharpPINVOKE'
>   threw an exception."}

The exact same code in .NET Core 2.0 creates the factory. Also made sure to install the latest Visual C++ Redistributables for 2017

Comment: Also come across this issue when trying to use this SDK in a botframework. web api.

Answer (score 3):

Could you please check the platform setting when building your application? For .NET Framework, the platform must be set to either x86 or x64, but cannot be AnyCPU.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes that did solve my problem too! Btw, you might want to force a rebuild on your project after you changed the build targe